# Is there a proof of (non)existence of a proper universal combinator?

Tags: combinatory-logic

It is a well-known fact that all combinators can be derived from the two fundamental combinators K and S.  It seems only natural to also ask whether there is a single universal combinator, but I can’t find much information on the topic. The only examples of universal combinators I can find are improper ones that refer to other combinators in its definition, such as [Chris Barker’s U combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iota_and_Jot). I also found [a discussion](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog%3aTomtom2357/Complete_Proper_Combinators) about the same question, but no definitive answers are offered there.

Is there a proof of (non)existence of a proper universal combinator, one that can be defined purely in terms of its own variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for *Craig's theorem*, which states that that there is no single proper combinator that is a  basis for combinatory logic.

(Craig's theorem is not any more general than that.)

One reference is [A new proof for Craig's theorem](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9083568&fileId=S0022481200032722) by Patrick Bellot.  I have not been able to find the entire paper online, only the abstract; if I find a better reference I will add it here.

(Unfortunately, it seems there is a much better-known Craig's theorem in mathematical logic which is completely unrelated. I have written to Bellot for details.)

Addendum 2016-03-09: The Bellot proof is only one page long, and is now [available from JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2274227) for free online viewing.  The citation given by Bellot is:

> H.B. Curry and R. Feys (with two sections by W. Craig), *Combinatory Logic*, Vol 1, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1958.

but he says that this proof “was shown to be incomplete by André Chauvin”.

Comment: I did not hear back from Bellot.